# Broken Image on website

Tags: html

I cannot get my image to load properly on my website.

The image file is located in : ~/node-js-sample/img 
The image file is titled: hhb.png with permissions 755 
The index.html file is located in ~/node-js-sample

I'm hosting the site on an aws server.

Please let me know if there is any additional information that could help.

Below is the code sample

```
    <div class="text-center logo">
        <a><img src="/img/hhb.png"></a>
        <span class="brand-headline visible-desktop">
            <p class="title-text">LOGO</p>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you mind accessing img file directly, for example through browser http://www.websitename.com/node-js-sample/img/hhb.png ?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? For example, what's the file with this HTML, and where is it located in relation to everything else?

Comment: Whoops sorry, just saw that info. See Maxamillian's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that your images need to be posted in the public folder, not the same folder the index.html file is located in.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is in a subfolder of where the html file is located, you need to use a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Instead of `<img src="/img/hhb.png">`, use `<img src="img/hhb.png">`.

Comment: That's not true if the img folder is in the root.

Comment: @j08691 The image folder is NOT in the root. It says clearly in the question that the image folder is `~/node-js-sample/img`, which is one directory down from the html.

Comment: I had removed the absolute path reference before to no avail.